# DNN Form & List XSLT Customization

Tags: xml, xslt, dotnetnuke

I am using the DotNetNuke core module, Form and List, and I need help styling an XSL sheet to

1. hide the form after a user fills it out using jquery;
2. show the node element udt:fields/fieldname [if fieldType=separator] above each section.

see example at http://osnc.newsura.com/BenefitLogin.aspx

UN: employer
PW: password

The XML is exactly as I need it. I am asking for help modifying the XSL stylesheet.

XML CODE:

```
<UserDefinedTable xmlns="DotNetNuke/UserDefinedTable">
  <Data>
    <UserDefinedRowId>10</UserDefinedRowId>
    <Blue_x0020_Shield />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_>fakeuser</Username_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_>
    <Password_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_>fakepassword</Password_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_>
    <Link_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_>fakelink</Link_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_>
    <Aetna />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_Aetna_x0029_>1</Username_x0020__x0028_Aetna_x0029_>
    <Password_x0020__x0028_Aetna_x0029_>2</Password_x0020__x0028_Aetna_x0029_>
    <Link_x0020__x0028_Aetna_x0029_>3</Link_x0020__x0028_Aetna_x0029_>
    <Principal_x0020_Financial_x0020_Dental />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_Principal_x0020_Financial_x0029_>4</Username_x0020__x0028_Principal_x0020_Financial_x0029_>
    <Password_x0020__x0028_Principal_x0020_Financial_x0029_>5</Password_x0020__x0028_Principal_x0020_Financial_x0029_>
    <Link_x0020__x0028_Principal_x0020_Financial_x0029_>6</Link_x0020__x0028_Principal_x0020_Financial_x0029_>
    <My_x0020_Secure_x0020_Advantage />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_My_x0020_Secure_x0020_Advantage_x0029_>7</Username_x0020__x0028_My_x0020_Secure_x0020_Advantage_x0029_>
    <Password_x0020__x0028_My_x0020_Secure_x0020_Advantage_x0029_>8</Password_x0020__x0028_My_x0020_Secure_x0020_Advantage_x0029_>
    <Link_x0020__x0028_My_x0020_Secure_x0020_Advantage_x0029_>9</Link_x0020__x0028_My_x0020_Secure_x0020_Advantage_x0029_>
    <Health_x0020_Butler />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_Health_x0020_Butler_x0029_>UN</Username_x0020__x0028_Health_x0020_Butler_x0029_>
    <Password_x0020__x0028_Health_x0020_Butler_x0029_>PW</Password_x0020__x0028_Health_x0020_Butler_x0029_>
    <Link_x0020__x0028_Health_x0020_Butler_x0029_>Link</Link_x0020__x0028_Health_x0020_Butler_x0029_>
    <FSA />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_FSA_x0029_ />
    <Password_x0020__x0028_FSA_x0029_ />
    <Link_x0020__x0028_FSA_x0029_ />
    <HSA />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_HSA_x0029_>13</Username_x0020__x0028_HSA_x0029_>
    <Password_x0020__x0028_HSA_x0029_>14</Password_x0020__x0028_HSA_x0029_>
    <Link_x0020__x0028_HSA_x0029_>15</Link_x0020__x0028_HSA_x0029_>
    <Created_x0020_by>Jason Hollis</Created_x0020_by>
    <Created_x0020_at>2012-01-12T15:02:47-08:00</Created_x0020_at>
    <Changed_x0020_by>Jason Hollis</Changed_x0020_by>
    <Changed_x0020_at>2012-01-17T16:47:11-08:00</Changed_x0020_at>
    <EditLink>http://osnc.newsura.com/BenefitLogin/tabid/275/ctl/edit/mid/898/Default.aspx?UserDefinedRowId=10</EditLink>
    <Created_x0020_by_UDT_Original>host</Created_x0020_by_UDT_Original>
    <Created_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>Jason Hollis</Created_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>
    <Created_x0020_at_UDT_Value>&lt;!--063461977367--&gt;1/12/2012 3:02 PM</Created_x0020_at_UDT_Value>
    <Created_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>634619773670000000</Created_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>
    <Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Original>host</Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Original>
    <Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>Jason Hollis</Changed_x0020_by_UDT_Caption>
    <Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Value>&lt;!--063462415631--&gt;1/17/2012 4:47 PM</Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Value>
    <Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>634624156310000000</Changed_x0020_at_UDT_Ticks>
  </Data>


    <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>80</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>898</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Blue Shield</FieldTitle>
    <Required>false</Required>
    <FieldOrder>0</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>Separator</FieldType>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>true</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValidationMessage>Please enter the name of the website associated with your account.</ValidationMessage>
    <ValueColumn>Blue_x0020_Shield</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Blue_x0020_Shield</SortColumn>
  </Fields>
  <Fields>
    <UserDefinedFieldId>81</UserDefinedFieldId>
    <ModuleID>898</ModuleID>
    <FieldTitle>Username (Blue Shield)</FieldTitle>
    <Required>false</Required>
    <FieldOrder>1</FieldOrder>
    <FieldType>String</FieldType>
    <Visible>true</Visible>
    <ShowOnEdit>true</ShowOnEdit>
    <Searchable>false</Searchable>
    <PrivateField>false</PrivateField>
    <NormalizeFlag>false</NormalizeFlag>
    <ValidationMessage>Please type your username for the account.</ValidationMessage>
    <ValueColumn>Username_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_</ValueColumn>
    <SortColumn>Username_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_</SortColumn>
  </Fields>


  <Data>
    <UserDefinedRowId>12</UserDefinedRowId>
    <Blue_x0020_Shield />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_>Employer UN</Username_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_>
    <Password_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_>Employer PW</Password_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_>
    <Link_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_>Employer Link</Link_x0020__x0028_Blue_x0020_Shield_x0029_>
    <Aetna />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_Aetna_x0029_>Employer UN</Username_x0020__x0028_Aetna_x0029_>
    <Password_x0020__x0028_Aetna_x0029_>Employer PW</Password_x0020__x0028_Aetna_x0029_>
    <Link_x0020__x0028_Aetna_x0029_>Employer Link</Link_x0020__x0028_Aetna_x0029_>
    <Principal_x0020_Financial_x0020_Dental />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_Principal_x0020_Financial_x0029_ />
    <Password_x0020__x0028_Principal_x0020_Financial_x0029_ />
    <Link_x0020__x0028_Principal_x0020_Financial_x0029_ />
    <My_x0020_Secure_x0020_Advantage />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_My_x0020_Secure_x0020_Advantage_x0029_ />
    <Password_x0020__x0028_My_x0020_Secure_x0020_Advantage_x0029_ />
    <Link_x0020__x0028_My_x0020_Secure_x0020_Advantage_x0029_ />
    <Health_x0020_Butler />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_Health_x0020_Butler_x0029_ />
    <Password_x0020__x0028_Health_x0020_Butler_x0029_ />
    <Link_x0020__x0028_Health_x0020_Butler_x0029_ />
    <FSA />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_FSA_x0029_ />
    <Password_x0020__x0028_FSA_x0029_ />
    <Link_x0020__x0028_FSA_x0029_ />
    <HSA />
    <Username_x0020__x0028_HSA_x0029_ />
    <Password_x0020__x0028_HSA_x0029_ />
    <Link_x0020__x0028_HSA_x0029_ />
    <Created_x0020_by>OSNC Employer</Created_x0020_by>
    <Created_x0020_at>2012-01-13T10:26:53-08:00</Created_x0020_at>
    <Changed_x0020_by>OSNC Employer</Changed_x0020_by>
    <Changed_x0020_at>2012-01-13T10:26:53-08:00</Changed_x0020_at>
  </Context>
</UserDefinedTable>
```

XSL CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:udt="DotNetNuke/UserDefinedTable" exclude-result-prefixes ="udt">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"  indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/udt:UserDefinedTable">
    <xsl:variable name ="imgColumn" select="//udt:Fields[udt:FieldType='Image'][1]/udt:ValueColumn"/>
    <xsl:variable name ="titleColumn" select="//udt:Fields[udt:FieldType='String'][CreatedBy]/udt:ValueColumn"/>
    <xsl:variable name ="htmlColumn" select="//udt:Fields[udt:FieldType='TextHtml'][1]/udt:ValueColumn"/>
    <xsl:variable name ="NameOfCurrentUser"        select ="udt:Context/udt:UserName"/>
    <xsl:variable name ="IsAdministrator"          select ="udt:Context/udt:IsAdministratorRole='true'"/>
    <xsl:variable name ="NameOfCreatedByColumn"    select="concat(udt:Fields[udt:FieldType='CreatedBy']/udt:ValueColumn, '_UDT_Original')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="per-row" select="number(4)" /> 

    <!-- Sorting Support-->
    <xsl:variable name="OrderBy">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test ="//udt:Fields[udt:UserDefinedFieldId=//udt:Context/udt:OrderBy]/udt:SortColumn">
          <xsl:value-of select ="//udt:Fields[udt:UserDefinedFieldId=//udt:Context/udt:OrderBy]/udt:SortColumn"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>UserDefinedRowId</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="OrderDirection">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test ="//udt:Context/udt:OrderDirection">
          <xsl:value-of select ="//udt:Context/udt:OrderDirection"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>ascending</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="OrderType">
      <xsl:variable name ="DataType" select ="//udt:Fields[udt:UserDefinedFieldId=//udt:Context/udt:OrderBy]/udt:FieldType"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$DataType='Int32' or $DataType='Decimal' or $DataType='Currency'">number</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>text</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="udt:Data">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4"  border="0"  style="border-width:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <xsl:for-each select="udt:Data[*[name()=$NameOfCreatedByColumn]=$NameOfCurrentUser]">
          <!--Sorting-->
          <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$OrderBy]" order="{$OrderDirection}" data-type= "{$OrderType}"/>

          <xsl:variable name="id" select="udt:UserDefinedRowId"/>
          <tr class="Normal">
            <td valign="top">
              <xsl:if test="udt:EditLink">
                <a>
                  <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="udt:EditLink" />
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <img border="0" alt="edit">
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                      <xsl:value-of select="//udt:Context/udt:ApplicationPath"/>/images/edit.gif
                    </xsl:attribute>
                  </img>Edit My Info
                </a>
              </xsl:if>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h2>
                <xsl:value-of select="udt:Created_x0020_by" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
              </h2>
              <xsl:value-of select="//udt:Data[udt:UserDefinedRowId=$id]/*[name()=$htmlColumn]" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <xsl:for-each select="//udt:Fields[(udt:FieldType!='CreatedBy' and udt:FieldType!='Separator' and udt:Visible='true') 
                                      or (udt:FieldType='CreatedBy' and udt:FieldType!='Separator' and $IsAdministrator)]">
                  <xsl:variable name="NameOfValueColumn" select="udt:ValueColumn"/>
                  <xsl:variable name="CurrentValue" select="//udt:Data[udt:UserDefinedRowId=$id]/*[name()=$NameOfValueColumn]"/>
                  <xsl:if test ="$CurrentValue and $CurrentValue!='' and ($NameOfValueColumn!=$imgColumn or not($imgColumn)) and ($NameOfValueColumn!=$titleColumn  or not($titleColumn)) and ($NameOfValueColumn!=$htmlColumn  or not($htmlColumn)) and (udt:Visible='true' or udt:Visible='True')" >
                    <tr class="Normal">
                    <td><!--<xsl:value-of select ="udt:FieldType=Separator"/>:-->

                    </td>
                      <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select ="udt:FieldTitle"/>:
                      </td>
                      <td>&#160;</td>
                      <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$CurrentValue" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please show the exact XML output you expect based on the input you've provided. That way nobody has to guess.

Comment: You should really trim this down into a more easily digestible form; as it stands now, it's just a wall of code and doesn't accurately convey your problem.  The community will *probably* vote to close this question as a result.

Comment: Please let me know if the edits I have made help better explain where I need assistance. Thank you for your pointers.